# Remove the duplicate lines from a file without sorting

Tags: linux

I am trying to remove the duplicate lines from a file without sorting in linux.

I have tried the below command:

```
 awk '!a[$0]++' file.tcl
```

But, it is throwing me an error:

```
 a[: Event not found.
```

Can anyone tell why the command is not working?

Note: I am not using bash as a shell.

Thanks & Regards,

Parth.

Comment: Which shell are you using then? Indeed it works just fine with bash.

Comment: Also: is this just a self-inflicted challenge or do you intend to use it in practice? If the latter, then do use sorting. The `awk` solution is cute but it loads the whole file in memory - not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found

Am unable to replicate your issue, works fine in bourne and bash.
Refer to this discussion.
Maybe you can attempt by adding a white space?